# Is it possible to have more than one ARIA live region on a page and have the screen reader announce both?

Tags: javascript, wai-aria, screen-readers

The default behavior when I have two live regions on my page is that the screen reader will only announce the text in one of them. Is there a way to get it to announce both? I've tried using a setTimeout() on one, as well as adding `aria-live="polite"` to one. Neither of these approaches works and I can't find much information online on having multiple live regions.

Comment: Do you have an example page to test it and tell us which OS, browser and screen reader you rare using ? As far as I remember, it worked...  perhaps no longer today, or not on several platforms.

Comment: I don't have an example page, but i'm working with macOS, Chrome, and the VoiceOver screen reader that's available on mac.

Answer (score 0):

Multiple live regions should work, but I've experienced aria-live regions not getting announced if they are in the wrong 'context' (i.e. the semantic roles of the wrapping elements).

For most predictable results, take care about where you place the live region in the DOM. The more deeply nested it is, the more likely it is to be 'hidden' from the screen reader. Consider that live regions do not need to be visible, so (in theory) they can be placed just inside the body, which is about as high-level as you can get.